# Blender baking png

Tags: image, baking, unity

I'm on a project where I want to animate a character's face with an image sequence and then open it in Unity to create a game. The thing is when the character is opened in Unity, the eyes part of the face (a duplicated mesh with 2 offsets of PNG images) can't be showed.

I have the whole body of the character and the eyes mesh in two objects. I tried to bake putting them together within one object by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> but I could not get to see the eyes in Unity.

If you have any idea to deal with this issue, I'd be glad to read the comments. I think it's all about the baking process.

Comment: It looks like a problem on the Unity side, so it seems to me we can't help you. Does your baked texture has the eyes or not ?

Comment: No, i've just checked it and it doesn't have the eyes once i bake the body. Could you tell me how to bake png on meshes? Thanks a lot

Comment: We would need a lot more informations, screenshots and even your blend file https://blend-exchange.com/. Are you sure you're trying to *Bake* your texture (which is a specific process) ?